# xpath contains text starts-with

Tags: selenium, xpath

I need to match this "foo" element with selenium:

```
<div class="d95 abc 123">foo</div>
```

but there are many foo's on the page, so i need to include the beginning of the class name "d95 ". I tried:

```
//div[text()[contains(.,"foo")] starts-with(@class, "d95 ")]
```

but this gives me:

```
InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //div[text()[contains(.,"foo")] starts-with(@class, "d95 ")] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.
```

I'm looking for this piece of code for quite a while, but I can't see what's wrong. If anybody could give me a hint, this would help me a lot.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

the point and `text()` in the case are the same. And both conditions are for `div`. So we can combine them with `and`

```
//div[contains(.,"foo") and starts-with(@class, "d95 ")]
```

Comment: this did not match, if i do it seperately, first matching my div with text foo, and than checking if it has the correct class i get the element i want.

Answer (score 0):

This works ?

```
//div[text()='foo'][starts-with(@class, "d95 ")]
```

Comment: this also did not mach